# Query the items related to current user in template

Tags: python, django

I have two models in my Django app like the following:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    # some movie-related fields

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

So users can rate any movies they want.
I have also a templated named `index.html` and here is how I'm sending the data to this template using the `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    movies_list = Movie.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(movies_list, 8)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    movies = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies': movies})
```

The `index.html`:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    {{movie.title}} <br />
    # The rating score that current user has gave to this movie in the iteration
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried the following, but it displays all scores that all users have given to the movie, not only the current user:

```
{% for rating in movie.rating_set.all %}
    {{rating.score}}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display the score that current user (that is seeing the movie page) has given to the movie in the `index.html` page?

Comment: Let me clarify. Do you want to list only Movies that were rated by current user and with scores?

Comment: @SergeyPugach Not exactly. I want to list all movies and in each movie's section display the score that current user has given if there is a score related to this movie and user in the database (and leave the score section empty if not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it with subquery, no need to query from template. Here is how.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

def index(request):
    score = Rating.objects.filter(movie=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user).values('score')
    movies_queryset = Movie.objects.annotate(user_score=Subquery(score[:1]))
    paginator = Paginator(movies_queryset, 8)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    movies = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies': movies})
```

Then just use user_score to access the value.

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    {{movie.title}} <br />
    {{ movie.user_score }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The `{{movie.user_score}}` displays nothing in the template. But when I add `print(movies[0].user_score)` to the `views.py`, I can see the related score in the terminal.

Comment: @Saeed what is the output of `print(movies[0].user_score)` ?

Comment: the score of the current user to the first item in movies queryset (an integer number).

Comment: I was using the Django's pagination in the view and after removing the pagination, your soultion works fine. How can I have the pagination too?

Comment: @Saeed post your final view with pagination and I'll help you to make those changes.

Comment: I updated the question with the pagination in the `views.py`.